# CSS 3D Horizontal Wheel Slider managed by Scroll

Tags: css, scroll, 3d, slider

I would like to make a 3D wheel slider managed by the natural ScrollBar like this :

[image]

It's liket an horizontal 3D Wheel Slider where the previous and the next items are smaller than the "current" one, and the other ones are hidden behind the scene

I would like to do it with a normal horizontal scrollbar to let the people scroll normally on the wheel, but i'm not sure it's possible to do something like this...

This is what I have for now :

```css
 ul {
  width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;

  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
ul::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
  background: #6A90CA;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Do you think this is possible to do or I should change my approach ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can use `view-timeline`, but it's not cross browser yet [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/view-timeline). If you want the focused slide to animate larger on drag, you probably just need to stick with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know about this property, it's kinda interesting but as you said it's not cross browser and I can't use it :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $swiper = $(".swiper-container");
  var $bottomSlide = null;
  var $bottomSlideContent = null;
  var mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    spaceBetween: 1,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    roundLengths: true,
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 30,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.swiper-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100px;
}

.swiper-container>.swiper-slide__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  &.swiper-slide-active {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: #3333
  }
}

.swiper-slide__content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i already thought about this solution (with plain JS not including something else). If i asked my question here it's because i want to know if there's a better and lighter way to do it !